# Can a VM swap to host main memory.?

Tags: vmware, swap

While my developer machine has a lot of memory, my vmware VM is 32 bit only and needs some swap space. Can I make it to swap into the host memory?

If so, is it possible to use [compressed swap space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18437205/difference-between-zram-and-zswap) for this in case the host memory gets exhausted? I want to avoid swapping to disk as it's damn slow compared to anything else.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. But I doubt that there is something like zram on your VM-server.

Back to "yes you can": Even though this is a 32-bit VM you can easyly utilize more than 4 GB RAM if you use the pae-variant for your kernel.

So allocate more RAM to your VM and reboot with pae-kernel.

Instead of swapping you will have more ram available - and vmware is doing memory-overcommittment, afaik.

Answer (score 0):

Pure 32 bit kernels limit total memory to around 3GB (This will depend on the settings).

All 32 bit kernels (including PAE) limit memory per process to around 3GB (Depending on settings), but PAE extends total memory (used by all processes).

With a 64 bit kernel, 32 bit processes can use 4GB (no settings involved).

On debian, you can switch kernel, after installing a 32bit system (maybe while).

This is true independent of swap. And you can not use the host RAM to give more than you could have with swap.